# Facebook og:image when multiple sections in web page can be shared?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a web site where there are two sections of content that should be shareable on Facebook.
With this code I can pull some content into the share dialogue

```
FB.ui({
method: 'share',
href: 'http://sampledomain.com/my_test',
quote: score,
...
```

The image that is getting pulled into the dialog is the one I set in a meta tag in the head, like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sampledomain.com/sampleimage.png" />
```

Problem is that I have 2 different share setups. This images ends up in both.
Is there a way to have 2 different images (or more) and make them populare depending on what button I have clicked to share?

Thanks for any hints in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Feed Dialog instead and set the picture on your own: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine